# What is difference between authorization, authorization advice, authorization adjust and reauth

Tags: iso8583

I am confused the use case of these four types. Any idea how to differentiate them?
authorization, authorization advice, authorization adjust and reauth.

Answer (score 3):

In a basic payment flow, the payable amount from your payment request is authorised and then captured. ... In this payment flow you can increase or decrease the authorised amount at a later stage, and then capture the payment. We refer to these changes to a pre-authorised payment as authorisation adjustments.

The authorization is a request from the client (POS, ATM, etc.) to authorize a transaction and lock funds. The advice is a notification sent by the client about something that already happened.

[image]